# Error when loading blazor app from server GET https://web.cpsk12.org/surplus/_content/Radzen.Blazor/Radzen.Blazor.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: c#, iis, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have deployed my bazor.server successfully to iis and it loads the index but when I load the webapp via url I get the following errors in the chrome dev console:

```
       GET https://web.cpsk12.org/surplus/_content/Radzen.Blazor/Radzen.Blazor.js net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
blazor.web.js:1 [2024-03-21T22:15:50.441Z] Information: Normalizing '_blazor' to 'https://web.cpsk12.org/surplus/_blazor'.
blazor.web.js:1 [2024-03-21T22:15:50.850Z] Warning: Failed to connect via WebSockets, using the Long Polling fallback transport. This may be due to a VPN or proxy blocking the connection. To troubleshoot this, visit https://aka.ms/blazor-server-using-fallback-long-polling.
log @ blazor.web.js:1
startConnection @ blazor.web.js:1
await in startConnection (async)
startCore @ blazor.web.js:1
start @ blazor.web.js:1
or @ blazor.web.js:1
await in or (async)
nr @ blazor.web.js:1
startCircutIfNotStarted @ blazor.web.js:1
resolveRendererIdForDescriptor @ blazor.web.js:1
determinePendingOperation @ blazor.web.js:1
refreshRootComponents @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
setTimeout (async)
rootComponentsMayRequireRefresh @ blazor.web.js:1
onDocumentUpdated @ blazor.web.js:1
Ki @ blazor.web.js:1
blazor.web.js:1 [2024-03-21T22:15:51.760Z] Error: There was an unhandled exception on the current circuit, so this circuit will be terminated. For more details turn on detailed exceptions by setting 'DetailedErrors: true' in 'appSettings.Development.json' or set 'CircuitOptions.DetailedErrors'. 
log @ blazor.web.js:1
unhandledError @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
_invokeClientMethod @ blazor.web.js:1
_processIncomingData @ blazor.web.js:1
connection.onreceive @ blazor.web.js:1
_poll @ blazor.web.js:1
await in _poll (async)
connect @ blazor.web.js:1
await in connect (async)
_startTransport @ blazor.web.js:1
_createTransport @ blazor.web.js:1
_startInternal @ blazor.web.js:1
await in _startInternal (async)
start @ blazor.web.js:1
_startInternal @ blazor.web.js:1
_startWithStateTransitions @ blazor.web.js:1
start @ blazor.web.js:1
startConnection @ blazor.web.js:1
startCore @ blazor.web.js:1
start @ blazor.web.js:1
or @ blazor.web.js:1
await in or (async)
nr @ blazor.web.js:1
startCircutIfNotStarted @ blazor.web.js:1
resolveRendererIdForDescriptor @ blazor.web.js:1
determinePendingOperation @ blazor.web.js:1
refreshRootComponents @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
setTimeout (async)
rootComponentsMayRequireRefresh @ blazor.web.js:1
onDocumentUpdated @ blazor.web.js:1
Ki @ blazor.web.js:1
blazor.web.js:1 [2024-03-21T22:15:51.761Z] Error: Circuit has been shut down due to error.
log @ blazor.web.js:1
unhandledError @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
_invokeClientMethod @ blazor.web.js:1
_processIncomingData @ blazor.web.js:1
connection.onreceive @ blazor.web.js:1
_poll @ blazor.web.js:1
await in _poll (async)
connect @ blazor.web.js:1
await in connect (async)
_startTransport @ blazor.web.js:1
_createTransport @ blazor.web.js:1
_startInternal @ blazor.web.js:1
await in _startInternal (async)
start @ blazor.web.js:1
_startInternal @ blazor.web.js:1
_startWithStateTransitions @ blazor.web.js:1
start @ blazor.web.js:1
startConnection @ blazor.web.js:1
startCore @ blazor.web.js:1
start @ blazor.web.js:1
or @ blazor.web.js:1
await in or (async)
nr @ blazor.web.js:1
startCircutIfNotStarted @ blazor.web.js:1
resolveRendererIdForDescriptor @ blazor.web.js:1
determinePendingOperation @ blazor.web.js:1
refreshRootComponents @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
setTimeout (async)
rootComponentsMayRequireRefresh @ blazor.web.js:1
onDocumentUpdated @ blazor.web.js:1
Ki @ blazor.web.js:1
blazor.web.js:1 [2024-03-21T22:15:51.771Z] Warning: Failed to deliver completion notification for render '5'.
log @ blazor.web.js:1
completeBatch @ blazor.web.js:1
await in completeBatch (async)
processBatch @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
_invokeClientMethod @ blazor.web.js:1
_processIncomingData @ blazor.web.js:1
connection.onreceive @ blazor.web.js:1
_poll @ blazor.web.js:1
await in _poll (async)
connect @ blazor.web.js:1
await in connect (async)
_startTransport @ blazor.web.js:1
_createTransport @ blazor.web.js:1
_startInternal @ blazor.web.js:1
await in _startInternal (async)
start @ blazor.web.js:1
_startInternal @ blazor.web.js:1
_startWithStateTransitions @ blazor.web.js:1
start @ blazor.web.js:1
startConnection @ blazor.web.js:1
startCore @ blazor.web.js:1
start @ blazor.web.js:1
or @ blazor.web.js:1
await in or (async)
nr @ blazor.web.js:1
startCircutIfNotStarted @ blazor.web.js:1
resolveRendererIdForDescriptor @ blazor.web.js:1
determinePendingOperation @ blazor.web.js:1
refreshRootComponents @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
setTimeout (async)
rootComponentsMayRequireRefresh @ blazor.web.js:1
onDocumentUpdated @ blazor.web.js:1
Ki @ blazor.web.js:1
blazor.web.js:1 
        
        
       DELETE https://web.cpsk12.org/surplus/_blazor?id=FzYfsnWPZVoytwfoCPAdSQ 403 (Forbidden)
send @ blazor.web.js:1
send @ blazor.web.js:1
send @ blazor.web.js:1
delete @ blazor.web.js:1
stop @ blazor.web.js:1
await in stop (async)
_stopInternal @ blazor.web.js:1
await in _stopInternal (async)
stop @ blazor.web.js:1
_stopInternal @ blazor.web.js:1
stop @ blazor.web.js:1
disconnect @ blazor.web.js:1
unhandledError @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
_invokeClientMethod @ blazor.web.js:1
_processIncomingData @ blazor.web.js:1
connection.onreceive @ blazor.web.js:1
_poll @ blazor.web.js:1
await in _poll (async)
connect @ blazor.web.js:1
await in connect (async)
_startTransport @ blazor.web.js:1
_createTransport @ blazor.web.js:1
_startInternal @ blazor.web.js:1
await in _startInternal (async)
start @ blazor.web.js:1
_startInternal @ blazor.web.js:1
_startWithStateTransitions @ blazor.web.js:1
start @ blazor.web.js:1
startConnection @ blazor.web.js:1
startCore @ blazor.web.js:1
start @ blazor.web.js:1
or @ blazor.web.js:1
await in or (async)
nr @ blazor.web.js:1
startCircutIfNotStarted @ blazor.web.js:1
resolveRendererIdForDescriptor @ blazor.web.js:1
determinePendingOperation @ blazor.web.js:1
refreshRootComponents @ blazor.web.js:1
(anonymous) @ blazor.web.js:1
setTimeout (async)
rootComponentsMayRequireRefresh @ blazor.web.js:1
onDocumentUpdated @ blazor.web.js:1
Ki @ blazor.web.js:1
blazor.web.js:1 [2024-03-21T22:15:51.820Z] Information: Connection disconnected.
blazor.web.js:1 Uncaught Error: No interop methods are registered for renderer 1
    at A (blazor.web.js:1:14023)
    at blazor.web.js:1:13929
    at D (blazor.web.js:1:14112)
    at R (blazor.web.js:1:13903)
    at P.dispatchGlobalEventToAllElements (blazor.web.js:1:16505)
    at P.onGlobalEvent (blazor.web.js:1:15698)
```

here is my program.cs code:

```
using Radzen;
using Surplus.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Surplus.Data;
using Blazored.LocalStorage;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents().AddInteractiveServerComponents().AddHubOptions(options => options.MaximumReceiveMessageSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024);
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddRadzenComponents();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<AppDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
builder.Services.AddSession();
builder.WebHost.UseStaticWebAssets();


builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
});
builder.Services.AddScoped<CSPNumerManager>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("Surplus").AddHeaderPropagation(o => o.Headers.Add("Cookie")).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler { UseDefaultCredentials = true });
builder.Services.AddHeaderPropagation(o => o.Headers.Add("Cookie"));
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, Surplus.ApplicationAuthenticationStateProvider>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddScoped<Surplus.SecurityService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<Surplus.WASPOService>();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<Surplus.Data.WASPOContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("WASPOConnection"));
});
var app = builder.Build();
// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();
app.UseAntiforgery(); // Add this line to include the Antiforgery middleware
app.UseHeaderPropagation();
app.MapRazorComponents<App>().AddInteractiveServerRenderMode();
app.Run();
```

and my app.razor code

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="@NavigationManager.BaseUri" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/material3-base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css" />
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="@InteractiveServer" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="@InteractiveServer" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
    <script src="_content/Radzen.Blazor/Radzen.Blazor.js"></script>
    <script src="./focus.js"></script>
    <script src="./printFunctions.js"></script>

    <script>
        window.setFocus = function (selector) {
            var element = document.querySelector(selector);
            if (element) {
                element.focus();
            }
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

iis file permissions are set to read write and execute for everything in this folder. and nothing via the firewall is blocking the app, so  I have no idea hat I am missing and am on a time crunch any help would be absolutely amazing!!!

thanks in advance!

Comment: For us, it is impossible to reproduce your problem, the best way is to use failed request tracking, it will provide the key error and warning, which will help you to identify the problem.
This link provide the method to enable failed request tracing to capture the detailed error:
https://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis.
If you still cannot solve the problem and it is urgent, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: Did you do that thing recommended in the error, and set development mode on so you can get detailed errors out? - *There was an unhandled exception on the current circuit, so this circuit will be terminated. For more details turn on detailed exceptions by setting 'DetailedErrors: true' in 'appSettings.Development.json' or set 'CircuitOptions.DetailedErrors'*